# PHP dynamic dropdown menu Get Value by ID

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database

Here's the background info for my question: I'm selecting data from an SQL table, which has the columns "ID (osm_id)", "Names" and "Coordinates (way)" with around 300 entries each. I got a dropdown menu to work displaying all the possible names of pubs (they are in column "Names").

Now I wanna get the *coordinates* *of a selected pub* and have those displayed on the page.
Here's my code so far:

```php
<?php 
    ...
    $query = "SELECT osm_id, name, ST_asText(ST_transform(way,4326)) FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE amenity LIKE 'pub' ORDER BY name ASC;";
    
    $result = pg_query($query) or die("Query error: " . pg_last_error());
?>
<select id="pub_select" name="pub_select" size="1">
<option value="">--- Select a Pub ---</option>

<?php
    $options='';
    while($line = pg_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $pub_id = $line[0];
        $pub_names = $line[1];
        $way_coords = $line[2];
        $options.="<option value='" . $pub_names . "'>$pub_names</option>";
        echo $options;
    }
    

    pg_free_result($result);
    pg_close($dbconn);
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get building coordinates" />
```

My tutor suggested that I could use:

```html
<select id="pub_select" name="pub_select" size="1" onchange="getMoreInfo()">
```

and call a function `getMoreInfo()` in order to do the detailed query (Pub ID -> Pub coordinates) and use `pub_select = document.getElementById('pub_select');` for the ID in Javascript/Ajax-Call of my php code and basically filter with the ID to get the coordinates. But I dont know how to do that :/

---

**EDIT:**
So, basically my question is: I have a database table, I choose a pub from a drop down menu. How do I get further information from the same table, like the coordinates from the corresponding column.

Comment: What have you tried to get this working? There are tons of tutorials out there that tell you how to get started wit AJAX. If you want to avoid AJAX, store the coordinates as data atrributes, or in any other format within your markup

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the HTML you generate slightly to include a `dataset` attribute for each `option` in the select menu.
The Javascript event handler `getmoreinfo` will read that dataset attribute and use it in part of an ajax request to some backend php script that will fetch more results from the db.

```
<select id='pub_select' name='pub_select' size='1' onchange='getmoreinfo(e)'>
    <option selected disabled hidden>--- Select a Pub ---
    <?php
        while( $line = pg_fetch_row( $result ) ){
            printf(
                '<option value="%s" data-latlng="%s">%s',
                $line[0],
                $line[2],
                $line[1]
            );
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

A simple version of what you might use in the `getmoreinfo` function to send an ajax request using the `fetch` api.

```
<script>
    function getmoreinfo(e){
        /* choose the correct path for backend script */
        let baseurl='/path/to/backend/script.php';
        
        /* create the request payload */
        let args={
            'latlng':e.target.dataset.latlng,
            'id':e.target.value
        };
        
        /* generate the full url & querystring for the GET request */
        let url=baseurl + '?' + Object.keys(args).map(key=>{
            return [ encodeURIComponent(key), encodeURIComponent(args[key]) ].join('=')
        }).join('&');
        
        /* issue the ajax request */
        fetch( url )
            .then( r=>r.text() )
            .then( text=>{
                /* process the final response here */
                alert( text )
            })
    }
</script>
```

A pseudo-code version of the `backend` script that the ajax request is sent to... this is pseudo code and untested.

```
<?php

    # /path/to/backend/script.php
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset(
        $_GET['latlng'],
        $_GET['id']
    )){
        $latlng=$_GET['latlng'];
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        
        $sql='select from sometable where id=? and latlng=?';
        $stmt=$dbo->prepare($sql);
        #... etc
    }
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a few things. You can pass the selected value from the select element i.e.

`<select id="pub_select" name="pub_select" size="1" onchange="getMoreInfo(this.value)">`

In the Javascript code you would have

```
<script>
function getMoreInfo( value ) {
 ...
}
```

If you do not have to use AJAX to get the results you can plug this info into the option value i.e.

```
while($line = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    $data = implode( "|", $line );
    $pub_names = $line[1];
    echo "<option value='" . $data . "'>$pub_names</option>";
}
```

This will but the | delimiter between each piece of data.

In your JavaScript function you would extra it by:

```
<script>
function getMoreInfo( value ) {
  var data = value.split("|");

}
```

To sent the information out to the web page you need an element where you can display the data. Use a div i.e.

```
<div id='results'></div>
```

Now put your data into the div i.e.

```
<script>
function getMoreInfo( value ) {
  var data = value.split("|");
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Name : "+data[1]+"<br>Co-ords : "+data[2];
}
```

If you have to use AJAX then things get a lot more complicated.